# PHP Echo information and wait to remove it

Tags: php, output-buffering

What I'm trying to do in my code is show a set of numbers, wait for a specified amount of time, and then delete what was previously shown, and then show an input. I just started coding recently.

```
if(isset($_POST['Start'])){
ob_clean();
echo $num2;
sleep(2);
ob_clean();
echo "<form method='post' action=''>
(etc...)
```

Comment: You need to do this in Javascript on the client. Once the server has sent the data, it can't unsend it.

Comment: @Barmar What if the OP were to use unset?

Comment: What difference does that make? It's already been sent to the browser.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's not how it works, unset only works on variables. Normally PHP sends it's output as it's being generated, which is why sometimes only half a page gets sent when there's an error in the PHP. Using output buffers basically makes the script keep the generated output in memory, until flush is called, and then send it all, so as  said, what has been sent, cannot be unsent

Comment: @AdiBradfield Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: What would the Javascript code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data has been sent to browser, php can't impact it. My solution is when you show your input, you attached a javascript function. okay, i thinks this code will help you

```
<?php 
function flush_buffers(){ 
    //This function make buffer send with out some problem
    ob_end_flush(); 
    ob_flush(); 
    flush(); 
    ob_start(); 
} 
ob_start();
$title = "<span class='mytitle'>My Title</span>";
echo $title; //You send your information
flush_buffers();

$input = "<input type='text'>"
$js_code = "<script type='text/javascript'>$('.mytitle').remove()</script>";//with jQuery :)
echo $input.$js_code;
flush_buffers();
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Start'])){
ob_clean();
echo $num2;
sleep(2);
ob_clean();
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
die;
} else {
echo "<form method='post' action=''>
(etc...) }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work the way you think it would. [See this link](http://3v4l.org/iJRNT)